# In C , translating a chararacter array as a character literal

Tags: c

What I want to do is be able to get in a character array and interpret it as a character literal.

For example if after:

```
fgets (buffer, 60, fp);
```

I have "Hello World! \n" in `buffer`, I want to be able to do afterward

```
printf(buffer);
```

and have the sequence `"\n"` be treated as a newline the same way as if I had written:

```
printf("Hello World! \n");
```

in the first place. I do understand that in the char literal '\n' is a single char while it is 2 in the char array.

Want to know if there is another way than to scan the char array for escape sequences.

Thank You

Comment: Use `printf("%s", buffer);` instead. It's good to avoid the habit of passing non-literals as the format string in `printf` because that kind of practice can open you up to accidental buffer overflow attacks.

Comment: Oh, I _think_ you're talking about your buffer containing an _actual_ backslash character. It's confusing because you are showing this as if it's code. In that case, just scan the string and parse/translate any encountered escape sequence, and shuffle bytes to the left.

Comment: If you're asking how to convert the two-character string into a LF, you'lll have to write the code yourself.

Comment: `\n` is a single newline character everywhere. If your buffer contains a backslash followed by n, that's `"Hello World! \\n"`.

Comment: Did you mean that you typed in `\n` into stdin and that you in C terms rather have got `"\\n"` there? Because otherwise, yes fgets will very likely leave a new line character in the buffer, that's the normal state of affairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own code that recognizes two character sequences of a backslash and another character, and converts them to the equivalent single character. Basic example that just echos standard input back out to standard output:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char buffer[512];
  int offset = 0;

  while (fgets(buffer + offset, sizeof buffer - offset, stdin)) {
    offset = 0;
    for (char *c = buffer; *c; c++) {
      if (*c == '\\') { // Handle backslash escapes
        c++;
        switch (*c) {
        case '\\': // \\ to \
          putchar('\\');
          break;
        case 'n': // \n to newline
          putchar('\n');
          break;
        case 't': // \t to tab
          putchar('\t');
          break;
          // etc.

        case 0: // backslash at end of input; need to read more
          buffer[0] = '\\';
          offset = 1;
          c--; // So *c is still 0 in the for loop test
          break;

        default:
          fprintf(stderr, "Unknown escape sequence: \\%c\n", *c);
        }
      } else { // just print other characters
        putchar(*c);
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Example of it in use:

```bash
$ gcc -o demo -g -O -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=address,undefined demo.c
$ cat <<<"foo\nbar"
foo\nbar
$ ./demo <<<"foo\nbar"
foo
bar
```